# How I can test a performClick action on a word inside the ClickableText widget

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-testing

I'm writing ui tests for my widgets and I can't find a way how the specific word in the ClickableText widget can be found and clicked after.

When I try to find a Node with a some text inside, it will find the whole node with all text. Here is the example that should be tested

```
val wordThatShouldBeTested = "someword"
val mainText = "Some main text that contains someword"
val wordThatShouldBeTestedIndex = mainText.indexOf(wordThatShouldBeTested)
val someAnnotatedText = buildAnnotatedString {
            append(someText)

            addStyle(
                style = SpanStyle(
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold
                ),
                start = wordThatShouldBeTestedIndex,
                end = wordThatShouldBeTestedIndex + wordThatShouldBeTested.length
            )

            addStringAnnotation(
                tag = wordThatShouldBeTested,
                annotation = wordThatShouldBeTested,
                start = wordThatShouldBeTestedIndex,
                end = wordThatShouldBeTestedIndex + wordThatShouldBeTested.length
            )
        }


          ClickableText(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(
                bottom = 16.dp
            ),
            text = someAnnotatedText,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1.copy(
                color = Abbey
            ),
            onClick = {
                someAnnotatedText.getStringAnnotations(
                    tag = wordThatShouldBeTested,
                    start = it,
                    end = it
                ).firstOrNull()?.let {
                    // Do some action
                }
            }
        )
```

I saw that some people are trying to find a bounds of the specific text but I'm still don't understand how can I archive that.

Could someone provide me an example please?

Comment: can you provide you actual or similar composable?

Comment: I provided in the example above